# ГАРНО - ГАРМОНИЯ

Tags: этимология

Как независимо от истории обосновать, что старо-славянское слово ГАРНО ("хорошо, красиво") имеет основу в латинском HARMONIA ? 
Ведь откуда-то должны были появиться слова: ГАРМОНЬ, гармоника, ОРГАН, ГАРМОНИЯ, ГАРМОТАТЬ ("греметь"), ГАРМОТУШКА (тамб., нижегор. "бубенчик, гремушка").

В латинском это такие слова, как ORGANICUS - музыкальный, поющий, музыкант, ORGANUM - музыкальный инструмент
В греч. HARMONIA - дочь Марса и Венеры, HARMONICA - учение о гармонии.
В итал. и исп. это ARMONIA - гармония.
В турецком ARMONIK - гармошка, баян.
Даже в финском HARMONIKKA - гармонь, баян.

Или ГАРНО - ГАРМОНИЯ это всего лишь совершенно случайное совпадение по графике и смыслу?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, русское слово "гарный" и украинское слово "гарний" можно соотнести со словами "гарнир и гарнитур", которые восходят к фр. глаголу garnir - украшать. Гармония происходит от греческого слова harmos - связь, соединение. Поэтому нельзя исключить их родство, но и каких-то сведений о наличии родственных связей пока найти не получается.

(Слово "гарнитур"заимствовано из немецкого, где garniture – «украшение, убор», куда пришло из французского. Изначально слово «гарнитур» называло всякое украшение (одежды, мебели, помещения), позже его значение сузилось, и в современном языке гарнитуром называют полный комплект, набор).

Comment: Нет. Гарнир (гарнитур) - позднее образования.

Нем. ГАРНИР - ZUKOST (или приправа) 
Во французском из русского ЗАКУСКА получилось ZAKOUSKI ("закуска").
Вероятно в силу обстоятельств, подобных русскому БЫСТРО, ставшее французским БИСТРО.